# Regex pattern for non-English string in Google Forms

Tags: regex, google-forms

I have a regex pattern `^\W*(\w+(\W+|$)){1,20}$` which i use to restrict a string to 20 words. But problem is, this applies only to English language, when there is non-English language text, this throws error immediately.

I need to write a regex expression to restrict a string to 20 words, string can be in any language.

Note: I am using this regex in Google Forms.

Comment: First, you have to define what a "word" is in every language. That's not an easy task (hint: whitespace between characters isn't how you do it).  As an alternative, perhaps you should re-think your constraint.

Comment: Google Forms uses RE2 library that does not support lookarounds. Try `^\P{L}*\p{L}+(?:\P{L}+\p{L}+){0,19}$`. Although these are said to be there, I am not sure the Unicode properties are supported.

Comment: Thanks all for your quick replies !! I tried with ^\P{L}*\p{L}+(?:\P{L}+\p{L}+){0,19}$ but that's not working. I think i need to think some other alternative solution.

Comment: That means you should narrow down your requirements. Say, you may use `^\W*?\S+(?:\W+?\S+){0,19}\W*$`. However, it is very inefficient, but maybe RE2 deals with such patterns better than regular NFAs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is close to impossible for linguistic reasons (well okay, not impossible, but quite difficult, expensive, and would require a whole team of people). Text written in for example Japanese or Mandarin does not need to have any spaces between words. Also, the `\w` code is equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, and `\W` is `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` , which does not include for example german umlauts, russian alphabet, other European extensions. What do you need that for? If it's supposed to be your length restriction I suggest you just search for average word length and multiply it by 20 (which would be about 6 * 20)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. It was my mistake that i was assuming in every language whitespace between characters denotes a word but as @Flimzy pointed out, i can't assume that. So need to think of an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

For languages where words are separated with spaces - you can try this formula:

```
^(\S+(\s+|$)){1,34}$
```

In [this example](https://regex101.com/r/WROr4B/2) content is limited to 34 words

Comment: Thanks Agnius !! This is working as expected except when there is newline '\n' in the string.

Comment: you are wellcome